# Send email to the user who executed the job in GitHub

Tags: github, github-actions

How could I send an email when I finish executing the Action in Github and send an email to the user who executed it? This is possible?

I have this for now, I have it at the end of my .yml file

```
    name: Send mail
  if: always()
  uses: dawidd6/action-send-mail@v3
  with:
    # mail server settings
    server_address: smtp.example.com
    server_port: 25
    # user credentials
    username: example@example.com
    #password: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_PASSWORD }}
    # email subject
    subject: Test ${{ github.job }} execution finished ${{ job.status }}
    # email body as text
    body: ${{ github.job }} job in worflow ${{ github.workflow }} of ${{ github.repository }} has ${{ job.status }}
    # comma-separated string, send email to
    to: example@example.com
    # from email name
    from: GiHub example
```

The problem is that I don't know how to send the mail to the user who executed the action. For example `${{ github.actor }}`, but I need the email of the user not only the username.

Answer (score 2):

There is a GitHub Action that successfully fetched an email for me: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-github-email-from-username

```
get_user_email:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
name: A job to get a users email
steps:
  - name: get email
    id: test
    uses: evvanErb/get-github-email-by-username-action@v1.25
    with:
      github-username: ${{ github.triggering_actor }}
      
  # Use the output from the `test` step
  - name: Print the found email
    run: echo "The email is ${{ steps.test.outputs.email }}"
```

In this example I use the [GitHub context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) to fetch the triggering_actor (the user that ran the job). This could solve your problem.